# Recursively finding indices of a string

Tags: java, string, recursion, slice

I'm trying to write a code that returns an Array whose elements are the indices of the word(occurences) that I'm looking for in a string :
ex)
d
Input:

```
String sent = "Hi is Hi is Hi is";
String find = "Hi";

ArrayList<Integer> index = indexFinder(sent,find);
For(int i=0;i<index.size(),i++)
    System.out.println(index.get(i));
```

Output:

```
0
6
12
```

It would be very nice if Java had a string slicing function like python.. but since it does not.. I tried to use substring() method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class recursionEx {
ArrayList<Integer> index = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> indexFinder(String sent, String find){
    int pos =0;
    int subPos =0;
    if(sent.contains(find)==false){
        return index;
    }
    else if(sent.contains(find)){
        pos = sent.indexOf(find);
        index.add(pos);
        subPos = pos+find.length();
        return indexFinder(sent.substring(subPos),find);
    }
    return index;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sent = "Hi is Hi is Hi is";
    String find = "Hi";
    recursionEx r = new recursionEx();
    ArrayList<Integer> g = r.indexFinder(sent, find);
    for(int i=0;i<g.size();i++){
        System.out.println(g.get(i));
    }

}

}
```

the output was

```
0
4
4
```

In hindsight, I'm gettng the substring of the original String sent every iteration, thus elements in index Array are the indices of the **String find** in substring of **String sent** which are 0,4,4.

How can I fix this to get the desired output?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just a side note: instead of calling `sent.contains(find)` you could just call `indexOf()` and check whether the return value is lower than 0 in which case the search string wasn't found.

Comment: yep, I changed my if statment to if(sent.indexOf(find)==-1). Thanks

Comment: I have the feeling you misunderstoof me: don't just replace `contains()` by `indexOf() == -1` but call `indexOf()` only _once_ and check the index. What I mean is (pseudocode) `index = indexOf(whatever); if( index >= 0 ) { add( index); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the substring as parameter, but only the start of the search in the string. Here is a way that works, it is not perfect, try to make it better :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class recursionEx {
ArrayList<Integer> index = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String string;
recursionEx(String string){this.string = string;}

ArrayList<Integer> indexFinder(int position, String find){
    int pos =0;
    int subPos =0;
    if(string.substring(position).contains(find)==false){
        return index;
    }
    else if(string.substring(position).contains(find)){
        pos = string.substring(position).indexOf(find) + position;
        index.add(pos);
        subPos = pos+find.length();
        return indexFinder(subPos,find);
    }
    return index;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sent = "Hi is Hi is Hi is";
    String find = "Hi";
    recursionEx r = new recursionEx(sent);
    ArrayList<Integer> g = r.indexFinder(0, find);
    for (Integer pos : g)
        System.out.println(pos);

}

}
```

Comment: You have several solutions : (1) pass as parameter always the whole string and the position of the start of the substring to analyse. (2) pass the substring to analyse and the position of the start of the substring.  Il all case you need 3 parameters : What you search, in what your search and a position.

Comment: oops I accidentally deleted my comment. Thank you for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add the length of the former substring to each following output, then you get the correct numbers. You can calculate these lengths by the older indices.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I think this is along the same lines as what A. Ocannaille suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use recursion to find the indices of substrings but rather use `indexOf(searchstring, offset)` until you don't find the search string anymore.

Alternatively use regex, i.e. `Pattern` and `Matcher` and collect the `group(0)` indices.

**Edit**:

Since you want to use [recursion](https://www.google.com/search?q=g%20recursion&rct=j#q=recursion) you could change the loop into recursive calls. In that case you could just pass the offset to the recursive call as well and keep using `indexOff(find, offset)`.

If you want to do it using `substring()` you'd also have to keep track of the substring's position in the original string and add that to the results of `indexOf(find)`, otherwise you get the indices relative to the substring only.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! but I'm trying to use recursion just for pracitice purposes :D

Comment: @LookAtTheBigPicture I see, you can still use that with recursion, however. Taking substrings would change the indices unless you add the index of the substring again.

Comment: yep, I think that's what  happend with my code. Should I just add the index to the pos(int variable)?